# Send faulty rows to other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a table with many columns in which I have to find the duplicate based on one column.

I.e. if I found duplicate `customer_name` in the `Customer_name` then

1. I have to remove all repeating from the source table.
2. Send all those rows to other table with same structure.

Comment: @phillyd I am able to delete the duplicate rows but I am not able to send them to other table

Comment: But that is removing the second duplicate, I want all corrupted/faulty rows to the other table. I want to remove all duplicate not the second occuring duplicate

Comment: What are you using to find the duplicate rows? Seeing the code would help. I feel like the OUTPUT clause may help you:

Comment: Mmmh ... My answer isn't good then ... How do you determine which one of the duplicate rows is the one you want to keep ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (ID int, customerName varchar(64))
CREATE TABLE t2 (ID int, customerName varchar(64))
```

You can make something like this:  (The ID column is for just to have a base for the deceision what to keep, you can change it as you need)

```
--First Copy

WITH CTE_T1
AS
(
SELECT
  ID,
  customerName,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customerName ORDER BY ID) as OrderOfCustomer
  FROM 
  t1
)
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT ID, customerName FROM cte_T1
WHERE OrderOfCustomer > 1;

--Then Delete

WITH CTE_T1
AS
(
SELECT
  ID,
  customerName,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customerName ORDER BY ID) as OrderOfCustomer
  FROM 
  t1
)
DELETE FROM CTE_T1
WHERE OrderOfCustomer > 1
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e9e3/13) to show how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I guess each row has a unique Id primary key.

This inserts into your duplicate rows table :

```
Insert into duplicateRowsTable
select * from myTable t1
where (select count(*) from myTable t2 where t1.customerId = t2.customerId) > 1
```

You delete from the duplicateRowsTable the good rows:

```
delete from duplicatesTable
where --this is not the faulty row for each customerId
```

finally you delete from your first table :

```
delete from myTable
where id IN (select id from duplicatesTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

For moving duplicates

```
INSERT Into DuplicatesTable
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_name ORDER BY Customer_name) As RowID,
FROM SourceTable)  as temp
WHERE RowID > 1
```

For deteting:

```
WITH TableCTE
AS
(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_name ORDER BY Customer_name) AS RowID
FROM SourceTable
)
DELETE
FROM TableCTE
WHERE RowID> 1
```

Comment: Insert won't work, because of SELECT *, because you have the extra RowID column, so it will try to insert one more column then it should.

Comment: @András Yes, I am aware of that but OP has not given the schema. While using he can remove the Select * & Take the columns he need from the select query.